# How to display a window with the page and the SizeToContent property in the center of the owner?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an opening window with the following properties:

```
<Window x:Class="Shdb.Windows.PopupWindow"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
<DockPanel>
    <Frame x:Name="PopupFrame" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"></Frame>
</DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Main window:

```
<Window x:Class="Shdb.MainWindow"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
</Window>
```

The owner is set like this:

```
PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow { Owner = mainWindow };
popupWindow.PopupFrame.Navigate(new MyProfile());
popupWindow.ShowDialog();
```

Also, the first window contains a DockPanel and a Frame in which a window with arbitrary sizes is located. When setting the `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` property, the `WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"` property stops working properly.The entire popup is displayed at the bottom right of the owner's center. How to display a window with a page in the center of the owner, while the window takes the width and height of the page?

Comment: Please show us your code. Do you set owner on the popup window?  You've considered using a popup control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it this way, but there seems to be a better way to do it. The handler is added to the page that is in the popup window.

```
        MainWindow mainWindow = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;

        private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window popupWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);

            if (mainWindow.Width > popupWindow.Width)
                popupWindow.Left = mainWindow.Left + (mainWindow.Width - popupWindow.Width) / 2;
            else
                popupWindow.Left = mainWindow.Left - (popupWindow.Width - mainWindow.Width) / 2;

            if (mainWindow.Height > popupWindow.Height)
                popupWindow.Top = mainWindow.Top + (mainWindow.Height - popupWindow.Height) / 2;
            else
                popupWindow.Top = mainWindow.Top - (popupWindow.Height - mainWindow.Height) / 2;
        }
```